# how to fix "Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined"

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am getting below errors while editing & saving the changes into zion page builder & I used the theme kallayas

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined
>   color-picker.min.js .close (color-picker.min.js)
>   HTMLInputElement. (widget.min.js)

Please help if someone knows how to get rid of this.

Comment: we need code. Does the error message give a file and line number? Looks like you are doing something like $myvar->addclass when $myvar is not defined as an object that has the addclass property/function. There could be any number of reasons.

Comment: the file is in wp-admin/js/ "color-picker.min.js:1:307 "

Comment: I see, this is a javascript error that appears in your browser when you save the page? Does this break something on your site? Does it happen on all pages? It may be OK to ignore the error and wait for an update to the theme.

Comment: because of this error, i cant edit & save the pages & it happens on all the pages where page builder was used....We don't know when theme is going to update ???

Comment: this seems to be a similar issue https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43331

Comment: i tried this solution but it wont work. was still not able to save the changes & it will throw the error. color-picker.min.js this file trow the error with that code.

Comment: i got the solution to comment the /dist/jswp-color-picker-alpha.js some code which calls the color-picker script & now everything is working fine...